# iOS 14 Widgets: Widget not rendering when list is used

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios14, swiftui-list, widgetkit

I'm experimenting with iOS 14 widgets and have a weird issue. My widget is not loading when I'm using a `List` in the widget view. If I'm using `HStack`, `VStack` etc. all works ok.

Here is some simple code for the sake of example:

```
struct WidgetView: View {

   var body: some View {
    
       List {
           Text("Test 1")
           Text("Test 2")
       }
   }
}
```

I'm seeing this image as a result:
[image]

Again, it all works well with other elements, this is only happening with `List`.

Comment: I think it because Widget cannot have a scrolling function

Comment: Widgets are not interactive (except tap to open app), so why do you need List? Use stacks.

Answer (score 13):

List has a scrolling function not supported on the widget, widgets only display static views, instead try using forEach.

### For example:

```
struct SomeView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(1..<5) { index in
                otherView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You may use an HStack, or VStack depending on your needs and design.

Answer (score 10):

Widgets do not support scrolling, this limitation is talked about in the [meet widget video of apple](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10028/) (you can fast forward to 12:02 in the video)

I had the exact same issue and there are two parts to resolve this

1. Make sure your model confirms to the `Identifiable` protocol OR at least has one field which acts as the primary key

Example: let's assume you had a structure named Task

```
   struct Task: Identifiable {
   let title,id:String
   }
```

and here's how the `TimelineEntry` structure looks like

```
struct TaskEntry: TimelineEntry {
let tasks: [Task]
let date: Date
}
```

2. Once you do that you can use the `ForEach` loop to construct your view using an array

   ```
   struct ToDoAppWidgetEntryView : View {
   var entry: Provider.Entry

   var body: some View {
    VStack{
        ForEach(entry.tasks, id:\.id){
            item in
            Text(item.title)
            Divider()
        }
       }
      }
   }
   ```

This is how the preview looks like

[image]

Comment: Hi there, im using this exact approach. but im getting the repeated task 1 title instead of title 1 and title 2.. :/

Comment: Make sure their identifier is unique